# Excel export with php not working for some reason

Tags: php, excel, export

So I know that in order to export a database table to excel in php, you put headers, and below that, you put the echo of what you want contained in the file. However, the file comes up empty. The code is below - it's really simple. I'm not even trying to export the table from the database at this point, I'm just trying to get it to write something, anything, but for some reason, it's not working. Does anyone have an idea on what the problem could be? Thanks!

```
<?php

require_once('../core/settings.php'); 
require_once('../core/auth_check.php');

      $db = getDB();

      if (isset($_POST["formExcelDownload"])) {

        $filename = "haha.xls";
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

        echo "HEHEY!";
      }

    ?>      

<form method="post" name="myAddForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input type="submit" name="formExcelDownload" id="formExcelDownload" value="Download" class="btn btn-primary" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: "for some reason" - honestly? You just issue the text "HEHEY!" and headers that pretend it's a Excel document... do you think the Excel binary format is created automagically? Use a proper library to create Excel files..

Comment: Wait a second - whatever is echoed after the headers is whatever gets written into the excel file, right? I had a table from the database echoed in there, but the result was the same. I removed it and replaced it with placeholder text "HEHEY!" as part of the bugfixing process. Also, what do you mean"pretend" it's an Excel document? I looked up like 20 tutorials on the subject and this is how literally all of them do it.

Comment: I bet _they_ issue a _real_ excel document, which is how it's done. The header is only a hint for the client, like "hey, here comes your data, treat it as Excel". But if you then don't send a valid Excel, you're fooling the client. Excel, for sure, won't treat "HEHEY!" as valid content for its document format :)

Comment: But I did have a table in there, like I said, from the database, even changed it a few times, once even replacing it with a hand-written table, but it didn't work. Oh well, guess I'll keep trying.

Comment: You could issue CSV data.. Excel knows to handle it.